# Getting List items as data.frame

Tags: r

I hope you can help me with something. Here would be some demo-code

```
library(gender)
library(tidyverse)

test1 = tibble::tribble(
  ~name1,      ~name2, ~name3, ~name4, ~name5,
  "PETER",      "KLAUS",     NA,     NA,     NA,
  "HEIKE", "ANTONIA",     NA,     NA,     NA,
  "SANDRA", "HEIKO", "HEIKO", "HEIKE", "HEIKE"
)

male_female_row <- list()
for (row in 1:nrow(test1)) {
  x1=gender(as.character(test1[row,]))
  y = table(x1$gender)
  male_female_row[[row]] = y
}

model2 = do.call(rbind.data.frame, male_female_row) ### List to dataframe
```

If you run this you can see that male_female_row is a list containing at [[1]] 2 male.

Now look in model2 and see that there is the 2 in both columns but considering the list there was no female so I want it to be 0. I want model2 and test1 to have the same amount of rows, basically just another column to mutate the list elements into test1.

Probably quite basic but I cannot get it right.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set factor levels to the gender variable as a solution :

```
male_female_row <- list()
for (row in 1:nrow(test1)) {
  x1=gender(as.character(test1[row,]))
  y=table(factor(x1$gender,levels=c("male","female")))
  male_female_row[[row]] = y
}

model2 = do.call(rbind.data.frame, male_female_row) ### List to dataframe
colnames(model2)=c("male","female")
```